# How to partially mock an object inside legacy code with OCMock?

Tags: objective-c, mocking, ocmock

I would like to accomplish what also is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18512663/1789384), i.e create mocks inside legacy code. However I require [*partial*](http://ocmock.org/reference/#partial-mocks) instead of *nice* [or *strict*](http://ocmock.org/reference/#strict-mocks-and-expectations) mocks.

For example, consider leaderboards that behave exactly like [`GKLeaderbaord`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLeaderboard_Ref/index.html) except for implementing a stubbed version of `loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:`.

I've tried this code inside an `XCTestCase` but it currently fails at runtime in the indicated line: `OCMInvocationMatcher` raises an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. Perhaps there is some infinite recursion going on.

```
id leaderboardMock = OCMClassMock(GKLeaderboard.class);
OCMStub([leaderboardMock alloc])
    .andReturn(OCMPartialMock([GKLeaderboard alloc]));
OCMStub([leaderboardMock loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: [OCMArg any]])
    .andDo(^(NSInvocation *invocation) { /* ... */ });

// these parts normally nested inside legacy code

GKLeaderboard *leaderboard = /* raises EXC_BAD_ACCESS */
    [[GKLeaderboard alloc] initWithPlayers: @[ GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer ]];
leaderboard.identifier = @"Test";

[leaderboard loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: nil /* ... */ ];
```

What am I doing wrong and is this even possible for partial mockups?

**UPDATE** I can by now see how the indicated line might (quite obviously) cause an infinite recursion, but don't yet know how to avoid (or break) it.

**UPDATE** I've also had no success with an attempt of bringing in an dedicated class with `OCMStub([leaderboardMock alloc]).andReturn([LeaderboardMock alloc])` (nor with `OCMStub([leaderboardMock initWithPlayers: [OCMArg any]]).andReturn([[LeaderboardMock alloc] initWithPlayers:nil])`). Perhaps `OCMock` does its magic at the level of `init` (the [documentation](http://ocmock.org/reference/#advanced-topics) says: "it is not possible to stub the `init` method, because that is implemented by the mock itself") hence such an attempt the level of `alloc` (or `initWithPlayers:`) cannot have its desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have by now concluded that [method swizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) would be a possible choice.

A replacement method could e.g. generate a partial mockup from within the context of legacy code and hence introduce a partial mock in that context without requiring changes to legacy APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I follow what you are trying to do. It seems like a misunderstanding. Does the following not work for you?

```
GKLeaderboard *leaderboard = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] initWithPlayers: ... ];
id leaderboardMock = OCMPartialMock(leaderboard);
OCMStub([leaderboarMock loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ...]);
```

You can use the normal object without restrictions. You can use the partial mock created for the object to manipulate the actual instance in `leaderboard`. That's the beauty of partial mocks.

**UPDATE**: If the object creation is not under your control, you can try the following:

```
GKLeaderboard *leaderboard = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] initWithPlayers: ... ];
id leaderboardMock = OCMPartialMock(leaderboard);

OCMStub([leaderboardMock alloc]).andReturn(leaderboardMock);
OCMStub([leaderboardMock initWithPlayers:[OCMArg any]).andReturn(leaderboard);

OCMStub([leaderboarMock loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ...]);
```

Comment: The problem (as I perceive it now) is that the leaderboard is created deep down in legacy code, which I cannot touch. Hence I have no means of placing the call `id leaderboardMock = OCMPartialMock(leaderboard);` between its creation and use (between your 1st and 3rd lines of code so to speak). See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18503604/1789384).

Comment: You can't mock the `init` method but `initWithPlayers:` should work. So maybe try mocking alloc/init.

Comment: For calling `OCMPartialMock` (as opposed to `OCMClassMock`) you need to know the instance of `leaderboard`. Unfortuntately, it is only known after its creation inside the legacy code base and not exposed by some API ...

Comment: BTW, mocking `initWithPlayers:` did not work for me either (as mentioned in Q.)

Comment: Have you tried to do this exactly like I suggest? I see in the original question that you are creating an object inside the stub setup, which means that you don't have a reference to it and therefore can't create a partial mock on it. Also, mixing a class mock and a partial mock and then stubbing class methods is bound to lead to problems, too. Hence, the specific solution I suggested in the updated answer.

Comment: But that's exactly the issue: outside the legacy code I don't have a reference, this is why the challenge occurs in the first place. One can deal with this in the case of weak/strict mock (see linked A), but evidently/so far not partial mocks.

Comment: In the code I posted in the update I create the instance, and set up the mock on that instance. This needs to happen early. I also stub the alloc/init... methods so that the legacy code, when it calls alloc/init will get the instance created in the test.

Comment: Thx for your effort, but this approach is not appropriate. (I've tried it before). What players (`...`) would you pass in "early" to match what the legacy code chooses "late"? IMHO there really would have to be a way for configuring mocked `alloc`s or `init`s such that they return new mocked instances (not just a singleton or pre-allocated instances perhaps from a pool).

Answer (score 0):

you should not use following line, it will mock your entire class and none of real object will get called.

OCMClassMock(GKLeaderboard.class)