# stub function is not working in my test case

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I am using [OCMock 3](http://ocmock.org/reference/) to write my unite tests in iOS project.

I have a `foo` method under `School` class:

```
@implementation School
-(NSString *)foo:
{
    // I need to mock this MyService instance in my test
    MyService *service = [[MyService alloc] init];

    // I need to stub the function return for [service getStudent]
    Student *student = [service getStudent];
    if (student.age == 12) {
       //log the age is 12
    } else {
      //log the age is not 12
    }
    ...
}
```

The `Student` looks like this:

```
@interface Student : NSObject
@property NSInteger age;
...
@end
```

In my test case, I want to stub the method call `[service getStudent]` to return a `Student` instance with `age` value 12 I defined:

```
// use mocked service
id mockService = OCMClassMock([MyService class]);
OCMStub([[mockService alloc] init]).andReturn(mockService);

// create a student instance (with age=12) which I want to return by function '-(Student*) getStudent:'
Student *myStudent = [[Student alloc] init];
myStudent.age = 12;

// stub function to return 'myStudent'
OCMStub([mockService getStudent]).andReturn(myStudent);

// execute foo method
id schoolToTest = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:[[School alloc] init]];
[schoolToTest foo];
```

When I run my test case, however, the `student` returned by `-(Student*)getStudent:` method is not with age 12, why?

**===== UPDATE ====**

I noticed in internet, somebody suggested to separate the `alloc` and `init` to stub. I also tried it but it doesn't work as it says:

```
// use mocked service
id mockService = OCMClassMock([MyService class]);
OCMStub([mockService alloc]).andReturn(mockService);
OCMStub([mockService init]).andReturn(mockService);
// stub function to return 'myStudent'
OCMStub([mockService getStudent]).andReturn(myStudent);
```

When I do this & run my test case, the **real implementation** of `-(Student*)getStudent:` method get called... I can't understand why people says it works.

Comment: As indicated in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18512663/765298) you need to separately mock `alloc` and `init` methods for this to work. I'd strongly suggest you'd redesign your code, so that the `School` object would take your `MyService` as parameter - this makes it easier to test and maintain. I'm also flagging your question as duplicate.

Comment: @Losiowaty, I tried separately mock `alloc` and `init`, it ends up running the real implementation.

Comment: @Losiowaty, See my update please. And I really want to know why people say it works but not working for me.

Comment: @Losiowaty, For me, the answer in the link you provided is not working with OCMock version 3. So, my question is not duplicated with anything.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind - does `MyService` actually override `init`?

Comment: Can you provide the entire test case from your update that isolates the problem to the MyService mock?

Comment: The problem here is that `init` is already implemented by the mock object, so when you call `[[MyService alloc] init]` your `alloc` stub successfully returns the mock object, but `init` returns something unexpected that is defined by `OCMock`'s implementation. The best solution to this (apart from using dependency injection) is to write a custom `init` method for `MyService` and stub that instead. Then make sure to change your `School` implementation to call `[[MyService alloc] customInitMethod]`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock the `init` method. This is stated in the documentation ([Section 9.3](http://ocmock.org/reference/#advanced-topics)), but maybe it's too hidden.

Comment: it's weird because ocmock2 allowed init stubbing. I don't know why they would remove that it's highly useful.

Comment: This will work again in the next version (3.4.2 or 3.5). See: https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/pull/351