# stub [[SomeClazz alloc] init] not work but accepted answer says it should work

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

My function under test is very simple:

```
@implementation MyHandler
...
-(void) processData {
  DataService *service = [[DataService alloc] init];
  NSDictionary *data = [service getData];
  [self handleData:data];
}

@end
```

I use [OCMock 3](http://ocmock.org/reference/) to unit test it.

I need to **stub** the `[[DataService alloc] init]` to return a **mocked instance**, I tried the [answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503604/how-to-mock-an-object-with-ocmock-which-isnt-passed-as-a-parameter-to-method) (which is an accepted answer) to stub `[[SomeClazz alloc] init]`:

```
// Stub 'alloc init' to return mocked DataService instance,
// exactly the same way as the accepted answer told
id DataServiceMock = OCMClassMock([DataService class]);
OCMStub([DataServiceMock alloc]).andReturn(DataServiceMock);
OCMStub([DataServiceMock init]).andReturn(DataServiceMock);

// run function under test
[MyHandlerPartialMock processData];

// verify [service getData] is invoked
OCMVerify([dataServiceMock getData]);
```

I have set break point in function under test, I am sure `[service getData]` is called when run unit test, but my above test code (OCMVerify) fails. Why?

Is it because the function under test is not using my **mocked** `DataService`? But the answer accepted in that question tells it should work. I get confused now...

I want to know how to stub `[[SomeClazz alloc] init]` to return mocked instance with OCMock?

Comment: I would encourage you to find a different design. The documentation says this about trying to stub alloc/init: "If you find yourself doing this a lot, please consider the dependency injection pattern. It is not possible to stub the init method, because that is implemented by the mock itself. "

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot mock `init` as it is implemented by the mock object itself. The reason that mocking `init` works in the answer you linked is because it is a **custom init method**. If you do not want to use dependency injection, you will have to write a custom `init` method for `DataService` that you can mock.

In your implementation add a custom `init` method:

```
// DataService.m
...
- (id) initForTest
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // custom initialization here if necessary, otherwise leave blank
    }

    return self;
}
...
```

Then update `MyHandler` implementation to call this `initForTest`:

```
@implementation MyHandler
...
-(void) processData {
  DataService *service = [[DataService alloc] initForTest];
  NSDictionary *data = [service getData];
  [self handleData:data];
}

@end
```

And finally update your test to stub `initForTest`:

```
id DataServiceMock = OCMClassMock([DataService class]);
OCMStub([DataServiceMock alloc]).andReturn(DataServiceMock);
OCMStub([DataServiceMock initForTest]).andReturn(DataServiceMock);

// run function under test
[MyHandlerPartialMock processData];

// verify [service getData] is invoked
OCMVerify([dataServiceMock getData]);
```

Feel free to rename `initForTest`, **so long as it isn't called `init`**.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this solution, since the second OCMStub() seems to be returning a class mock object for an init function that is expecting to return an instance method. I tried this technique for a similar problem and see an exception where it is failing to use the object returned from init, which is of type 'OCClassMockObject'.

Comment: How are you using the class mock object? It's tough to say what could be going on without seeing the code